# Data tidying on date/time

Tags: r, datetime, tidy

I have a very large dataset with date and time in a single column on 15-minute intervals corresponding to the data. Unfortunately the software recording the data has some issues and so randomly there are 15-minute intervals (usually 1 or 2 but sometime 3 and 4). The dataset is reported as follows:

```
   Date_and_time         Pressure
   2016-07-08 18:00:00    3.542
   2016-07-08 18:15:00    5:444
   2016-07-08 18:45:00    2:556
   2016-07-08 19:00:00    4:567
```

I am looking for a way to enter a row inbetween the missing time frames. My goal is to stack this data for multiple sites on top of each other I and I need to make sure for graphing purposes that the line up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can perfectly guarantee that all times are aligned on the quarter hour, then you could try this:

```r
tibble(Date_and_time = do.call(seq, c(as.list(range(dat$Date_and_time)), by="15 mins"))) %>%
  full_join(dat, by = "Date_and_time")
# # A tibble: 5 x 2
#   Date_and_time       Pressure
#   <dttm>              <chr>   
# 1 2016-07-08 18:00:00 3.542   
# 2 2016-07-08 18:15:00 5:444   
# 3 2016-07-08 18:30:00 <NA>    
# 4 2016-07-08 18:45:00 2:556   
# 5 2016-07-08 19:00:00 4:567
```

If you think there is a chance that your times are not *perfectly* aligned (even a fraction of a second will introduce unnecessary rows), then we can turn this into a problem of *"enforce a gap of no more than 15 minutes"*:

```r
dat %>%
  group_by(grp = cumsum(c(FALSE, as.numeric(diff(Date_and_time), units = "mins") > 15))) %>%
  summarize(Date_and_time = max(Date_and_time) + 15*60) %>%
  bind_rows(dat) %>%
  arrange(Date_and_time) %>%
  select(-grp)
# # A tibble: 6 x 2
#   Date_and_time       Pressure
#   <dttm>              <chr>   
# 1 2016-07-08 18:00:00 3.542   
# 2 2016-07-08 18:15:00 5:444   
# 3 2016-07-08 18:30:00 <NA>    
# 4 2016-07-08 18:45:00 2:556   
# 5 2016-07-08 19:00:00 4:567   
# 6 2016-07-08 19:15:00 <NA>
```

Notice that the last added row is unnecessary, that can be removed in a simple clean-up step. The premise of this second method is that it creates a group where everything within the group is gapped 15 minutes (or less), and then adds 15 minutes to the last one row. This ensures that there is no gap greater than 15 minutes, but:

1. It will always produce a single row at the bottom that may not be needed; and
2. It does not make any assurance of the gap between the added rows and the rows beneath them. For example, if your third row was instead at `"2016-07-08 18:31:00"`, then the time would sequence through `"18:15:00"`, `"18:30:00"`, then `"18:31:00"` (with a 1-minute gap).

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(Date_and_time = structure(c(1468015200, 1468016100, 1468017900, 1468018800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), Pressure = c("3.542", "5:444", "2:556", "4:567")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hi, I continue to get the error that Tibble columns must have compatible sizes and that only values of size one are recycled

Comment: Hello JackWassik, I cannot reproduce that error. Which code block isn't working for you? How is your real data different than the sample data in your question? Both of the code blocks work as-is on the sample data you provided (and I standardized).

Comment: Yes. I found the issue. Had a column that included site names. Once removed both code blocks worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a sequence that has all potential sampling times and then join your data to that.

```
library(tidyverse)
ALL_PERIODS <-data.frame(SAMPLE_TIME= seq.POSIXt(from = as.POSIXlt("2016-07-08 18:00:00"), to =as.POSIXlt("2016-07-08 20:00:00"), by = "15 min"))

SAMPLE_DATA <- data.frame(Date_and_time= as.POSIXlt( c("2016-07-08 18:00:00","2016-07-08 18:15:00","2016-07-08 18:45:00","2016-07-08 19:00:00") ), pressure=c(3.542, 5.444,2.556, 4.567))


ALL_PERIODS_DATA <- left_join(ALL_PERIODS,SAMPLE_DATA, by=c("SAMPLE_TIME"="Date_and_time"))
```